# REST API along with Websocket API

Tags: rest, http, websocket

I have to create an application with a permanent connection (I need to send data update from the server) and, in parallel, I need to configure this app. My idea was to use Socket.IO for the connection and use it also for the configuration, with specifics event name.

But someone said that it's better to keep Socket.IO only for sending data from the server and use a REST API to configure the app.

I want to know if using a REST API along with of a Websocket connection is a good practice or not, and if no, why.

Comment: *"someone say"* - who? Did you try asking *them* why they say that and whether they'd approve of your REST idea? Why don't you just *try something* and see how it works out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's my boss, he said that websocket doesn't replace REST (witch I agree) and I need a trusted document (Oracle, Google, etc...) to justify the use of Websocket, but I didn't find any documentation about using REST API **in parallel** of a websocket connection.

Comment: So you want us to find you some documentation? That's explicitly off topic here. Just talk to your boss and agree on an approach between you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not what I asked, I asked what is the best practice, if using REST API in parallel of Websocket is good or not.

Comment: And that's opinion-based, also off topic.

Comment: If it has a good answer it must be a good question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always can provide a REST API along with a WebSocket API for different purposes. It's up to your requirements and it depends on what you want to achieve.

For instance, you can use a WebSocket API to provide real-time notifications while the REST API can be used to manage resources.

There are a few details you should be aware of:

- REST is a protocol-independent architectural style frequently implemented over the HTTP protocol and it's meant to be stateless.
- In HTTP, the communication is driven by the client: the client requests and the server responds.
- WebSocket is a bi-directional, full-duplex and persistent connection protocol, hence it's stateful.
- In WebSockets, once the communication is established, both client and server can exchange frames in no particular order.

---

Just to mention one example of application that provides different APIs: Stack Exchange provides a [REST API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) along with a [WebSocket API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218343/278120).